# StreamInsight Wcf Sample with resiliency

Tags: wcf, streaminsight

I'm getting to know StreamInsight (v2.1!) and started working on an application based on the WCF Sample from the StreamInsight Team.
Now I would like to add resilience and monitoring to that application but can't figure out how. I've tried following the Checkpointing Sample and these tutorials but with no luck:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290476(v=sql.111).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391166(v=sql.111).aspx

Should I adapt the WcfObservable? Or how should I add resilience to my observable, observer and query?

This is part of my code:

```
var wcfIn = app.DefineObservable(() => new WcfObservable(wcfSourceURL));
var wcfStream = wcfIn.ToPointStreamable(i => PointEvent.CreateInsert<Measurement>(i.T, i.M),
                                             AdvanceTimeSettings.IncreasingStartTime);

//Check measurements for deflections
var deflectionQuery = from r in wcfStream
                      where r.Value > measurableValue * 1 + threshhold || r.Value < measurableValue * 0 + threshhold
                      select new OutputEvent
                      {
                           M = r,
                           Deflection = (r.Value - measurableValue) / measurableValue,
                           Error = "Deflection"
                      };
var sqlObserver = app.DefineObserver(() => Observer.Create<OutputEvent>(SqlWritePoint));
proc = deflectionQuery.Bind(sqlObserver).RunCheckpointable(procName);
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Your query logic doesn't look complicated. In your example, you aren't binding your deflectionQuery to your sqlObserver. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The query logic is indeed not so complicated in this case but once I know how to do the resiliency, I can add it to the other queries.
I added the line of code I use for the binding, I forgot it previously.